Controlling how a nuget package is included in the project
I have a library that has both an API and an analyzer. I will distribute it as NuGet package. Although I did not add any special thing to the csproj or nuspec, when the reference is added, it looks like this:
<PackageReference Include="Integration" Version="1.0.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>

But I want it to be included without filters, just the bare
<PackageReference Include="Integration" Version="1.0.0" />

What controls this behaviour, can it be influenced in the desired direction?
I know of the <DevelopmentDependency> tag, but it is not set in my .csproj.

It's controlled by the developmentDependency tag in the .nuspec file that's embedded in your package. You may not be setting it in your csproj, but evidently something is setting it by the time your package is created. The tool to debug msbuild is https://www.msbuildlog.com.  Do any MSBuild action with the -bl argument (for example dotnet pack -bl), it will create a msbuild.binlog file, then open it with the binlog viewer and slowly try to understand what's going on

setting it to false in .csproj directly solved the issue.

Setting <DevelopmentDependency> tag to false in .csproj made it work as I wanted it.
